# Pass value with href in php inside echo

Tags: php, html

I need to pass value with href inside fetch array echo...

**php code**

```
$user   =   $get['username']; 
$resource=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
          echo "<font color=\"#000000\">
          <h2 align=\"center\"></h2>

        <table align=\"center\" border=\"1\" width=\"50%\">
        <tr>
         <td><b>GROUP NAME</b></td> <td><b>TASK TITLE 1</b></td> <td><b>TASK TITLE 2</b></td> <td><b>CREATED BY</b></td> <td><b>ASSIGNED TO</b></td> <td><b>DUE DATE</b></td> <td><b>PRIORITY</b></td> <td><b>CHANGE</b></td></tr> ";
while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($resource))
    {
    echo "<tr><td>".$result[0]."</td> <td>".$result[1]."</td> <td>".$result[2]."</td> <td>".$result[3]."</td> <td>".$result[4]."</td> <td>".$result[5]."</td> <td>".$result[6]."</td> <td> "<a href="changetask1.php?username='.$user.'">"</td></tr>";
    } echo "</table></font>";
```

I need to pass username to next page with href value.

Comment: You know how to concatenate, so why don't you do that for the link tag too?!

Comment: As you have it your quoting is off on that part

Comment: can you rewrite above code so that it will be useful

Comment: You were used mis-matched single and double quotation echo "<tr><td>".$result[0]."</td> <td>".$result[1]."</td> <td>".$result[2]."</td> <td>".$result[3]."</td> <td>".$result[4]."</td> <td>".$result[5]."</td> <td>".$result[6]."</td> <td> <a href='changetask1.php?username=".$user."'></td></tr>";

Comment: You need to escape the one set of quotes.

Comment: echo "<tr><td>".$result[0]."</td> <td>".$result[1]."</td> <td>".$result[2]."</td> <td>".$result[3]."</td> <td>".$result[4]."</td> <td>".$result[5]."</td> <td>".$result[6]."</td><td> <a href='changetask1.php?username=".$user.">CHANGE</td></tr>";   now working but i am getting change button only on the first line of table and on second line i am getting <\/script>\  like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are all messed up with quotes...

**First**... Learn to indent your code to make it readable.
Then, avoid echoing simple HTML if not necessary:

See your code after my «formatting»:
Try it, i've done a couple corrections...

```
<?php
$user=$get['username']; 
$resource=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>

<!-- This is only HTML -->
<font color="#000000">
    <h2 align="center"></h2>
    <table align="center" border="1" width="50%">
        <tr>
            <td><b>GROUP NAME</b></td>
            <td><b>TASK TITLE 1</b></td>
            <td><b>TASK TITLE 2</b></td>
            <td><b>CREATED BY</b></td>
            <td><b>ASSIGNED TO</b></td>
            <td><b>DUE DATE</b></td>
            <td><b>PRIORITY</b></td>
            <td><b>CHANGE</b></td>
        </tr>

        <?php
        // This is a PHP block until the next ?>

        while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($resource)){
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>".$result[0]."</td>
                    <td>".$result[1]."</td>
                    <td>".$result[2]."</td>
                    <td>".$result[3]."</td>
                    <td>".$result[4]."</td>
                    <td>".$result[5]."</td>
                    <td>".$result[6]."</td>
                    <td><a href='changetask1.php?username=".$user."'></td>
                  </tr>";
        }
        ?>

    </table>
</font>
```

Comment: Patrice ...Your code is working fine.. but when i click change task id is seen on taskbar how to hide that?

Comment: You mean that the part `username=XYZ` is visible in the adress bar... Well Yes. You send it via a GET variable to your PHP script. You can't sent it as POST since you tag the reference on a link. That's life!

Comment: But you should look for `$_SESSION` variables... Wich will store this username in session... So then, no need to add it as a GET on the link. Reading here : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: I am maintaining session variable for username on every page. how to get task id through session on next page?

Comment: If you already have the username in session, in your `changetask1.php`, retrieve the `$_SESSION['username']` value... Instead of passing it in a link from the previous page.

Comment: Something like `$_SESSION['username']=$user;` in this «previous page will set the session value. In your `changetask1.php`, you wil get this value back with `$user=$_SESSION['username'];` DON'T FORGET about `session_start();` in all pages.

Comment: This is ok.but,I need to pass Taskid which i cannot get through session..Is it possible to send values in secure manner or it will be shown in address bar while transferring

Comment: I don't see anything like a «task id» in your code. But I suppose it is the ID of a specific line of the table. This could be added to the link as a GET since it is the user's choice...

Comment: Sorry instead of GROUP NAME im using TASK ID..so i need to pass ".$result[0]." Is there amyway i could pass securely

Comment: <?php
       while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($resource))
       {
           echo "<tr>
                   <td>".$result[0]."</td>
                   <td>".$result[1]."</td>
                   <td>".$result[2]."</td>
                   <td>".$result[3]."</td>
                   <td>".$result[4]."</td>
                   <td>".$result[5]."</td>
                   <td>".$result[6]."</td>
                   <td>".$result[7]."</td>
                   <td><a href='changetask1.php?taskid=".$result[0]."'>CHANGE</td>
                 </tr>";
       }
       }
       ?> This is actual

Comment: Then do this : `<td><a href='changetask1.php?taskid=".$result[0]."'></td>` and retreive it by `$taskId=$_GET['taskid'];` in changetask1.php. Instead of the username you already have.

Comment: Your last comment was exactly what I just suggested. ;) But you have a surplus `}` at the end. Cheers! you're on the right track!

Comment: Thanks....Will it be secure if anyone could change task id in address what will happen?

Comment: When i click change i could see http://localhost/eorg/changetask1.php?taskid=3   in address bar

Comment: You can secure it by checking the GET value this way `is_int(intval($_GET['taskid']))` will give you a TRUE. so you can use `intval($_GET['taskid'])`... It will block most of user's malicious attempts.

Comment: will check that. If u can send me those codes it will be useful

Comment: Everything is here : http://php.net/manual/en/ If you look for experienced hints, it's something else. Check my profile ;)

Comment: Great Profile.Congratz on self learning...Will try to learn and do that

Answer (score 0):

To avoid these problems of `double` and `single` quote you can write your code like following.

```
<td><a href="cheangetask1.php?username=<?php echo $user;?>"></td>
```

Now on the `changetask1.php` you can get username like this.

`<?php echo $_REQUEST['username'];?>`